# jquery ui autocomplete get result

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need an event, that gives me the data from the selected point in the list that jquery ui autocomplete creates.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the "select" event?

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  select: function( event, ui ) {
       //Put your code here:
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Event name is **select**. It is triggered when an item is selected.

You can find more details in [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Autocomplete#events)